# application crashed on orientation change

Tags: android, android-edittext, orientation

UPDATE: I had my problem solved by using

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

My application crashed when I tried to change orientation, and I have looked through several other threads and it doesn't seem to solve my issue.

I have tried to add in

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout"
```

and it doesn't work as well.

From the logcat, it seem to be caused by onTextChangedListener part but I have no idea why is it causing the issue.

```
05-02 01:13:45.132: D/AndroidRuntime(20683): Shutting down VM
05-02 01:13:45.132: W/dalvikvm(20683): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40afb930)
05-02 01:13:48.235: E/AndroidRuntime(20683): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-02 01:13:48.235: E/AndroidRuntime(20683): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{..../....Music}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-02 01:13:48.235: E/AndroidRuntime(20683):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
05-02 01:13:48.235: E/AndroidRuntime(20683):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2357)
05-02 01:13:48.235: E/AndroidRuntime(20683):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3819)
05-02 01:13:48.235: E/AndroidRuntime(20683):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:153)
05-02 01:13:48.235: E/AndroidRuntime(20683):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1253)
05-02 01:13:48.235: E/AndroidRuntime(20683):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-02 01:13:48.235: E/AndroidRuntime(20683):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-02 01:13:48.235: E/AndroidRuntime(20683):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5226)
05-02 01:13:48.235: E/AndroidRuntime(20683):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-02 01:13:48.235: E/AndroidRuntime(20683):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-02 01:13:48.235: E/AndroidRuntime(20683):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
05-02 01:13:48.235: E/AndroidRuntime(20683):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
05-02 01:13:48.235: E/AndroidRuntime(20683):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-02 01:13:48.235: E/AndroidRuntime(20683): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-02 01:13:48.235: E/AndroidRuntime(20683):    at ....Music$2.onTextChanged(Music.java:628)
05-02 01:13:48.235: E/AndroidRuntime(20683):    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7231)
05-02 01:13:48.235: E/AndroidRuntime(20683):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3699)
05-02 01:13:48.235: E/AndroidRuntime(20683):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3554)
05-02 01:13:48.235: E/AndroidRuntime(20683):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
05-02 01:13:48.235: E/AndroidRuntime(20683):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3529)
05-02 01:13:48.235: E/AndroidRuntime(20683):    at android.widget.TextView.onRestoreInstanceState(TextView.java:3429)
05-02 01:13:48.235: E/AndroidRuntime(20683):    at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:12093)
05-02 01:13:48.235: E/AndroidRuntime(20683):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2588)
05-02 01:13:48.235: E/AndroidRuntime(20683):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2588)
05-02 01:13:48.235: E/AndroidRuntime(20683):    at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:12071)
05-02 01:13:48.235: E/AndroidRuntime(20683):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.restoreHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:1634)
05-02 01:13:48.235: E/AndroidRuntime(20683):    at android.app.Activity.onRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:938)
05-02 01:13:48.235: E/AndroidRuntime(20683):    at android.app.ListActivity.onRestoreInstanceState(ListActivity.java:219)
05-02 01:13:48.235: E/AndroidRuntime(20683):    at android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:910)
05-02 01:13:48.235: E/AndroidRuntime(20683):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1131)
05-02 01:13:48.235: E/AndroidRuntime(20683):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2275)
05-02 01:13:48.235: E/AndroidRuntime(20683):    ... 12 more
```

And the line that probably caused the problem is here (I think).

```
editTxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                System.out.println("Text ["+s+"] - Start ["+start+"] - Before ["+before+"] - Count ["+count+"]");
                if (count < before) {
                    // We're deleting char so we need to reset the adapter data
                    ((MyMediaAdapter) adapter).resetData();
                }

                adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString()); <-- THIS IS LINE 628

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });
```

Update: Not sure if my AsyncTask has to do with it. So I'll just post it here.

```
private class AsyncFetchMedia extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        String toLoad;

        public AsyncFetchMedia (String toLoad) {
            this.toLoad = toLoad;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                // Fetching data

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return "Completed Loading " + toLoad + " Music List";
        }      

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            dialog.dismiss();

            adapter = new MyMediaAdapter(Music.this, getMediaList);
            setListAdapter(adapter);


        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(Music.this);
            dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {

        }
    }
```

Let me know if there is need for more information.

Comment: Where is your adapter getting initialized?

Comment: @Tom inside AsyncTask in onPostExecute part.

Comment: OK - looks to me like your adapter is null because it is not getting initialized properly after the orientation change...i.e. onCreate() because when you change orientations, your app gets destroyed and resumed...tough to tell though without your main activity code

Comment: @Tom I had it solved by using android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize", screenSize instead of screenLayout as I did previously and now it works. Thanks for your help though.